# T-SQL concurrent select and update statements

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, concurrency, sql-update

I have 2 SQL statements, that can be executed concurrently.
1st one updates request from Requests table, when request is taken for processing:

```
UPDATE Requests
SET IsInProcess = '1'
```

2nd one counts requests in process:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Requests
WHERE IsInProcess = '1'
```

I need to count requests only after update statement is finished.
What transaction isolation levels or table hints do I need to use to accomplish this ?

Comment: I'm not sure what "I need to count requests only after update statement is finished." is meant to mean - but as soon as you have multiple activities occurring in parallel, any computed result can potentially be out of date before you even act upon its value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use any. `READ COMMITTED` and default locking will do that. (Provided the update starts a bit earlier, otherwise the update will wait until you count.)

Given your `where` clause, it's likely the server will take `X` lock on the whole table. Event if it doesn't, the losing process will wait until the winning process releases its lock on the first updated/read row.